# Programming an Alpha electronic sign with Alphasign Python

Tags: python-2.7, sign, pyusb

I am trying to program an alpha sign - 215r - using the alphasign python api [Alphasign] (https://alphasign.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). I downloaded python 2.7, pyusb, pyserial, and libusb. I got the vid and pid of the sign using libusb and added that to the devices.py file. However, when I ran the example python code [here] (https://alphasign.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), I still got an error that said it could not find device with vid and pid of 8765:1234 (the example numbers). Now, when I open the file (the code is copied and pasted from the link above) it crashes IDLE (totally shuts down). ...when I run the file from bash, it says core dump. suggestions please!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a Mac (mtn lion): When I ran the sample app, I got a segment fault 11.  It was crashing in the alphasign library from the ***sign.connect()*** call.

Changed it to ***sign.connect(reset=False)***, and it worked fine.

FYI: The segment fault occurs in the low-level USB driver, libusb, not in python code.